# ionic 2 - converting a sentence string to array of words

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a string of words (they are separated by new line)

```
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
```

and I want to add it to an array "words"

```
[1] = aa
[2] = aaa
[3] = aaaa
[4] = aaaaa
```

how can I do this in ionic 2? I know in java it would look like this

```
String s = "This is a sample sentence.";
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    words[i] = words[i].replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
}
```

but can't figure it out in ionic 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript or Typescript you could do the same with:

```js
 const s = "This is a sample sentence.";
 const words = s.split(" ");
 
 // displaying the array
 for (word of words){
 console.log(word);
 }
```